# Delete all 0 kb / null file from SD card in specific folder or DCIM /camera/thumnail or subfolder too

Tags: android, image, htc-android

How can I delete all 0 kb / null files from SD card in specific folder or from DCIM /camera/thumnail or from subfolder too.

In my case I deleted last pic from my device inside capture and put the pic only in my app pic. as per my code its working fine in some device but in **HTC ONE M7** it show black thumb in device gallery and when I find the location of the pic it show me DCIM/camera but the pic size i get 0kb and image resolution is -1x-1. so is there any solution that I can delete all pic with size 0kb from DCIM folder...

this is my code

```
Cursor c = null;
    Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    getContentResolver().delete(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            BaseColumns._ID + "=?", new String[] { captureimageid });

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, BaseColumns._ID, };

    AppLog.i("InfoLog", "on activityresult Uri u " + u.toString());



    try {
        if (u != null) {
            c = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);
        }
        if ((c != null) && (c.moveToLast())) {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            int i = cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    BaseColumns._ID + "=" + c.getString(3), null);
            AppLog.i("TAG", "Number of column deleted : " + i);
        }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: plz give your code..